# Why does a SEGFAULT occur when calling a template class function?

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault

*NOTE: his problem is related to a Gazebo issue concerning the distruction of a GpuLaserPlugin object - 
for the original issue see [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2574/gpurayplugin-segfaults-on-shutdown), where there are also instructions for reproducing the issue)*

I've been having a segfault problem when trying to destroy a `Connection` object:

```
class GZ_COMMON_VISIBLE Connection
{
  public: Connection(Event *_e, const int _i);
  public: ~Connection();
  // Get the id of this connection.
  // The id of this connection.
  public: int Id() const;
  // The event for this connection
  private: Event *event = nullptr;
  private: int id = -1;
  private: common::Time creationTime;
  public: template<typename T> friend class EventT;
};
```

The destructor calls `Disconnect()` from the `EventT` template class, a child of the `Event` class:

```
class GZ_COMMON_VISIBLE Event
{
  public: Event();
  public: virtual ~Event();
  public: virtual void Disconnect(int _id) = 0;
  public: bool Signaled() const;
  public: void SetSignaled(const bool _sig);
  private: bool signaled;
};

...

template<typename T>
class EventT : public Event
{
  public: EventT();
  public: virtual ~EventT();
  public: ConnectionPtr Connect(const std::function<T> &_subscriber);
  public: virtual void Disconnect(int _id);

...

}

...

void EventT<T>::Disconnect(int _id)
{
  printf("Start disconnect \n");                                //for debug

  // Find the connection
  auto const &it = this->connections.find(_id);

  if (it != this->connections.end())
  {
    it->second->on = false;
    this->connectionsToRemove.push_back(it);
  }
  printf("End disconnect \n");                                  //for debug
}
```

The `Connection` destructor:

```
Connection::~Connection()
{
  gzwarn << "Start destructor \n";                                  //for debug

  if (this->event && this->id >= 0)
  {
    this->event->SetSignaled(true);
    bool eventBool = this->event->Signaled();                       //for debug
    std::cout << "ID value is " << this->id << std::endl;           //for debug
    std::cout << "Event bool value is " << eventBool << std::endl;  //for debug
    std::cout << typeid(this->event).name() << std::endl;           //for debug
    this->event->Disconnect(this->id);
    this->id = -1;
    this->event = nullptr;
  }
  gzwarn << "End destructor \n";                                    //for debug
}
```

Unfortunately when `Disconnect()` is called a segfault is thrown (full backtrace can be found [here](https://github.com/Michael-Purser/gazebo_test/blob/master/backtrace.txt))

I checked that `id` and `event` member variables still exist by printing their values and the event type before the function call:

```
[Wrn] [Event.cc:60] Start destructor 
ID value is 0
Event bool value is 1
PN6gazebo5event5EventE

Thread 1 "gzserver" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555719fd20 in ?? ()
```

What seems strange to me is that SEGFAULT occurs somewhere after the `Disconnect()` function call **but** before actually stepping into it (because the `Start disconnect` debug statement is never printed) which would suggest the problem lies with `id` or `event`, although according to the output these should exist.

Could anyone shed some light on why calling this function causes SEGFAULT?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. If the SEGFAULT occurs at one particular place, it doesn't mean that the problem is in that place. It can be due to undefined behavior anywhere in your code.

Comment: "Why does a SEGFAULT occur ..." - Because some part of your code is reading from or writing to memory outside its allocated address space and the kernels response to that illegal behaviour is to shut down your program with a SEGFAULT signal.

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ I/O.

Comment: You can't determine whether something exists by examining it. Successfully printing a value is evidence of nothing.

Comment: *I checked that id and event member variables still exist by printing their values* -- You will be disappointed to know that you cannot determine whether an item exists by printing the value.  You can have a value that looks "good", but be totally bogus.  In addition to that, you need to make sure all of those calls in the destructor do not `throw`.  If they do, your application will terminate if you haven't coded a `catch` for your destructor.

Comment: The `event` member of a `Connection` is initialised to `nullptr` by default. If that is not changed (e.g. by a constructor) then `this->event->Disconnect(this->id)` has undefined behaviour.  It will also have undefined behaviour if `this->event` does nt point at a valid object (e.g. points at an object that no longer exists).    There are many possible causes of your problem and, since you have not provided a [mcve], anyone trying to help you can only guess what your code is or is not doing that contributes to the symptom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.